# SoapUI Groovy: Check if test step is a soap request

Tags: groovy, soapui

Is there a way to check if a certain test step is a soap request?

Currently I have a `Groovy Script` at the end of the test case and looping through all the test steps to record the requests and responses.

I would like to ignore steps that aren't requests. I am accessing each step by using `context.testCase.getTestStepAt(i)` if this is relevant information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to find if the step is of specific type such as Wsdl, REST, Jdbc, HTTP, Groovy etc in a `Groovy Script` step.

Please the below script for the same.

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlTestRequestStep
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.RestTestRequestStep
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.JdbcRequestTestStep
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.HttpTestRequestStep

//....other stuff
//Initialise variable step before using it.
if (step instanceof WsdlTestRequestStep) {
    log.info "Found a request step of Wsdl/Soap type"
   //do the stuff you wanted

} else if (step instanceof RestTestRequestStep) {
    log.info "Found a request step of Rest type"
    //do the stuff you wanted   
} else if (step instanceof JdbcRequestTestStep) {
    log.info "Found a request step of jdbc type "
    //Do the stuff you wanted
} else if (step instanceof HttpTestRequestStep) {
     log.info "Found a request step of http type "
     //do the stuff for http                
}
```